# ES6/8 syntax - arrow functions

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

The two of the following result in different things although they look like the same thing.

## 1

```
const addBlogPost = dispatch => {
    return () => {
        dispatch({type: 'add_blogpost'});
    }
};
```

## 2

```
const addBlogPost = dispatch => dispatch({type: 'add_blogpost'});
```

Could anyone point out how are they different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [site](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) to compile es6 arrow functions to vanilla JS to easily see the difference.

The **first one** compiles to this

```
var addBlogPost = function addBlogPost(dispatch) {
  return function () {
    dispatch({
      type: 'add_blogpost'
    });
  };
};
```

While the **second** compiles to this

```
var addBlogPost = function addBlogPost(dispatch) {
  return dispatch({
    type: 'add_blogpost'
  });
};
```

The first returns a function that has a dispatch while the second one returns a dispatch directly.

Answer (score 0):

The result will always be the same as both functions are retuning the same thing.
 The only difference is:

1. In the first function, you're returning a function which returns an object that returns `dispatch` function.
2. In the second function, you're returning your `dispatch` function directly.